# How to count event frequencies in a time window in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have a dataframe in Pandas describing the sales of fruits made in different stores over a certain time period:

```
    Time_of_sale    Product     Store
05.01.2018 15:37    Apple        1
05.01.2018 13:58    Apple        1
05.01.2018 15:36    Banana       2
05.01.2018 15:33    Banana       3
15.08.2017 19:08    Strawberry   4
15.08.2017 19:04    Blueberry    4
03.09.2017 15:32    Pere         5
03.09.2017 15:31    Pere         6
05.01.2018 15:32    Blueberry    7
05.01.2018 15:27    Banana       2
08.01.2018 09:31    Grapes       1
```

What I would like to add to each row, is basically the amount of sales of this product in this store that have been made within a time window (for example 3 hours).

For example in the first row:

- How many Apples have been sold in store 1 within 3 hrs?

The result should therefore add a new column (so no downsampling).

```
Time_of_sale           Product         Store       Sales_in_TF
05.01.2018 15:37    Apple           1                2
05.01.2018 13:58    Apple           1                2
05.01.2018 15:36    Banana          2                2
05.01.2018 15:33    Banana          3                1
15.08.2017 19:08    Strawberry      4                1
15.08.2017 19:04    Blueberry       4                1
03.09.2017 15:32    Pere            5                1
03.09.2017 15:31    Pere            6                1
05.01.2018 15:32    Blueberry       7                1
05.01.2018 15:27    Banana          2                2
08.01.2018 09:31    Grapes          1                1
```

I was looking into

```
series.resample('3H', label='right').count()
```

as well as

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='3H', closed='left'))
```

But I cant really find what I'm looking for.
Maybe you guys have an idea?

Comment: Not sure what you need. Is column `Sales_in_TF`  count from your sample data? Your frequency is `3H` ? Or `90Min` ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right ofc. Lets say freq = 3H. I edited my post. So in the Sales_in_TF column it says: 2 Apples have been sold in store 1 within 3 hours. Same goes for Bananas in store 2, etc

Answer (score 0):

I create a dummy variable amount of all `1`s so it will count that.

```
df['Amount'] = 1
groups = df.groupby((
    pd.Grouper(key='Time_of_sale', freq='6H'),
    'Product', 
    'Store'
))
groups.count()
```

Results:

```
                                      Amount
Time_of_sale        Product    Store        
2017-03-09 12:00:00 Pere       5           1
                               6           1
2017-08-15 18:00:00 Blueberry  4           1
                    Strawberry 4           1
2018-05-01 12:00:00 Apple      1           2
                    Banana     2           2
                               3           1
                    Blueberry  7           1
2018-08-01 06:00:00 Grapes     1           1
```

Edit: Whoops didn't see you wanted downsampling. This isn't very elegant but you can do this:

```
dfs = []
for i, group in df.groupby((pd.Grouper(key='Time_of_sale', freq='6H'), 'Product', 'Store')):
    group['Amount'] = group.shape[0]
    dfs.append(group)
pd.concat(dfs)
```

Which doesn't downsample.

```
       Time_of_sale     Product  Store  Amount
2017-03-09 15:32:00  Pere            5       1
2017-03-09 15:31:00  Pere            6       1
2017-08-15 19:04:00  Blueberry       4       1
2017-08-15 19:08:00  Strawberry      4       1
2018-05-01 15:37:00  Apple           1       2
2018-05-01 13:58:00  Apple           1       2
2018-05-01 15:36:00  Banana          2       2
2018-05-01 15:27:00  Banana          2       2
2018-05-01 15:33:00  Banana          3       1
2018-05-01 15:32:00  Blueberry       7       1
2018-08-01 09:31:00  Grapes          1       1
```

Comment: This Looks exactly like what I need! Thanks for the quick help!